# Error 500 At Chrome and IE when signingout

Tags: google-chrome, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am building an ASP.NET Core APP with that performs identity management with Azure AD B2C using the ASP.Net Core OpenID Connect. At Client side I am using Angularjs 2 using typescript. My Logout function basically redirect to Account Controller.

```
logout() {
        window.location.href = "./Account/Logout";
    }
```

Majority time this works, but for some unknown reasons, Chrome and IE results Error 500 with no header description and it result into white page with nothing happened and user can still navigate back via back button.

I have searched the DOM and found following

> TypeError: Illegal invocation at Node.remoteFunction

Please help as I am running out of ideas as to why and why only in Chrome & IE

Thanks

Comment: Try use  window.location.href = "http://www.yoursite.xxx/Account/Logout";  i.e. (window.location.href = "http://localhost/Account/Logout")

Comment: Thanks - could you please let me know as to why I need to have full path into it.

Answer (score 0):

You forget add protocol, you can do that like :

Add param to your config in startup method

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.AddInMemoryCollection();
var config = builder.Build();
config["baseURL"] = "yourbaseurl";

//can get like this
var setting = config["baseURL"];
```

or web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="BaseURL" value="http://localhost/" />
</appSettings>
```

And you can read it also

```
window.location.href ="<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseURL"].ToString()%>/Account/Logout";
```

Comment: Thanks again - why this has to be a absolute path, why can't it be a relative path.

Sorry for asking too many questions - I am trying to understand why this different to other